# Authentication information in SOA env (Java)

Tags: java, public-key-encryption

My problem is simple.
I have a service oriented architecture where one of the servers is an auth server.
Users are authenticating with HTTPS in this server and then go to other servers with a token to get services.

My solution idea was this:
The auth server will generate two cookies, one with the actual data of the user (user GUID / session expiration date and privileges)
And another cookie with an encrypted token that includes the actual data (with some salt) encrypted with a private key.

Each server in the system will be able to make sure that the user is how it claims to be with the two cookies and the public key.

I need an example for such a code (or maybe a better solution if I missed anything)

Comment: What framework are you using for the servers?

Comment: Currently we've just implemented simple servlets with JSP but we will move to Spring MVC soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to reinvent the wheel, you could simply use [CAS](http://www.jasig.org/cas) for this single sign on functionaliy.

Comment: Thanx for the suggestion - CAS looks really interesting - I started to look into it for a more future prove solution.